# Pulling Neo4j docker image for Mac M1 chip

Tags: macos, docker, neo4j, apple-m1

I would like to pull the `neo4j` image on my Mac Book M1 machine.

The dockerfile is something like this

```
FROM neo4j:3.5.30-community
....
```

If I don't specify the target platform it gave me an error on pull :

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/neo4j:3.5.30-community                                                                                                                                     0.6s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/neo4j:3.5.30-community:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest     sha256:a3c8ec959f11ecac3e90c6c032afb217718128366b6ba3d59cf55ad6320be8d1: not found
ERROR: Service 'designer-neo4j' failed to build: Build failed
```

I google it a bit and I found that I need to do a:

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

This works and image is pulled and it runs - slow and with a lot of crashes...

Inside my docker dashboard, it warns me with a red exclamation mark: `amd64: Image may have poor performance...`. If I google it tells me, that I should have arm64 architecture images...

So how to pull the neo4j image on mac m1, so that it will work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a more recent version of Neo4j, 3.5 is EOL already.

If you do use 4.3 or 4.4 you will be able to simply pull arm64 compatible images.

Check on docker hub https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j?tab=tags&page=1 , you will see immediately the image tags compatible with arm64 architectures.

Comment: Thank you. I saw this one... But what if I need to pull this image (3.5.) for compatibility reasons... could I get away with this error?